# JNI initialization function and caching classes and fields

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

My JNI function returns ProcessedImage objects. The relevant class definitions in Java:

```
public class Thumbnail {
  public int size;
  public byte[] data;
}

public class ProcessedImage {
  public Thumbnail[] thumbnails;
  public byte[] hash;
}
```

My native function declaration looks like this:

```
public class ImageProcessor {
  // Called from different JVM threads.
  public static native ProcessedImage processImage(byte[] image);
  // Only called once.
  public static native initialize();
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("ImageProcessor");
    initialize();
  }
}
```

Now I want to write a native initialize function that does the following:

1. Fills a global matrix in native land. This matrix is later read in my processImage native function, but is immutable after this initialization.
2. Calls a GraphicsMagick init function.

(2) is easy since it needs to be called once. I am not sure what to do about (1). I could initialize the array here but it might not be visible to other Java threads which call the processImage function. May I assume that since this is in a static block this will get executed before any other JVM threads are created? This seems like a wrong assumption. What is the best way for me to make sure that this array is later visible to other JVM threads? I don't want to use locking to access/write to this matrix. If this were pure C/C++ I would do something like this:

```
__attribute__((constructor))
static void Initialize() {
  // Initialize everything here.
}
```

Another question is what is the best place to cache jclasses and jfieldIDs? Should I look them up in the initialize function and store them as globals. I read that this is not a good practice since jclass and jfieldIDs might become obsolete after a class gets unloaded and loaded again. The standard practice seems like one should do this in a static block within the class. Something like this:

```
public class Thumbnail {
  private static native initializeThumbnailNative();
  static {
    initializeThumbnailNative();
  }
  public int size;
  public byte[] data;
}
```

Since a class could get loaded and unloaded on a thread different from the one my native function processImage is being called from, my native function might not see the change to these global jclasses and jfieldIDs. What is the recommended way to handle this. Again I could lock access to these fields and retry the native method on an exception, but that doesn't seem right. Another hacky way that could possibly work is I could create single instances of all the classes in java and store them as statics so that there is always at least a single instance of these classes and they are never unloaded. So something like this:

```
public class ImageProcessor {
  public static native ProcessedImage processImage(byte[] image);
  public static native initialize();
  // Create a static instance to prevent these classes from being unloaded.
  private static Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
  private static ProcessedImage processedImage = new ProcessedImage();
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("ImageProcessor");
    initialize();
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this will work though. What would be the best way to achieve caching of jclasses and jFieldIDs in a multi-threaded application? I apologize in advance for the lengthy question but I wanted to provide maximum context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I'm late, I overslept (for a few months, yeah WW pop reference).

Anyway, you could look into JNI_OnLoad

Comment: I ended up using JNI_OnLoad actually.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that this is not a good practice since jclass and jfieldIDs might become obsolete after a class gets unloaded and loaded again.

A `jclass` or `jobject` can become invalid after the JNI method it was acquired in exits, let alone across class loads. If you store these statically at all you must do so as 'global refs' or 'weak refs'.

Comment: Aah. Got it. I am still not sure about the visibility of these statics to other threads.

Comment: I've answered that. 'If you store these statically ...'